# Como obter todas as possibilidades a partir de uma string incompleta

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma string, por exemplo, com 5 caracteres mas necessito da mesma ter 10 caracteres no total, fiz o seguinte codigo para tentar obter os 5 caracteres restantes para obter um total de 10 caracteres:

```
<?php
$letras = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numeros = '0123456789';
$tudo = $letras.$numeros;

$string = 'XXXXX';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($tudo); $i++) {
    echo $string.$tudo[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Retorno:

```
XXXXXA
...
XXXXX9
```

Gostaria que o retorno fosse, por exemplo, `XXXXXAAAAA`, `XXXXXAAAAB` e assim vai, entao fiz outro codigo para tentar obter a quantia exata de 10 caracteres:

```
<?php
$letras = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numeros = '0123456789';
$tudo = $letras.$numeros;

$minimo = 10;
$string = 'XXXXX';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($tudo); $i++) {
    $base = $string.$tudo[$i];
    for($j = 0; $j < strlen($tudo); $j++) {
        $base .= $tudo[$j];
    }
    echo $base.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Porem o codigo acima retornou o seguinte:

```
XXXXXXXAABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
...
XXXXXXX9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

Nao entendi porque do retorno retornar a variavel `$tudo` ao inves de retornar o resultado mais logico sendo:

```
XXXXXAAAAA
XXXXXAAAAB
...
XXXXX9AAAA
XXXXX9AAAB
```

Nos codigos aqui escritos, usei `echo` linha por linha para observar o retorno de cada tentativa, mas no codigo final gostaria que retornasse uma array, por exemplo:

```
array(
'XXXXXAAAAA',
'XXXXXAAAAB',
...
)
```

Agradeco qualquer solucao e/ou dica desde ja!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das várias possibilidade seria converter sua string de caracteres em uma instância da classe [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.arrayobject.php) criar alguns iteradores com o método [ArrayObject::getIterator()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/arrayobject.getiterator.php) e os iterar em cadeia para compor o resultado.

O iterador é um marcador de posição dentro uma lista de objetos que vai se deslocando conforme é iterado. [ArrayObject::current()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/arrayiterator.current.php) retorna o valor onde o iterador está apontando e  [ArrayObject::next()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/arrayiterator.next.php) o faz apontar para o próximo elemento. Para saber se o iterador extrapolou a lista de itens subscritos teste com [ArrayObject::valid()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/arrayiterator.valid.php)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A lógica de funcionamento é simples, primeiro são criados `m` iteradores indexados de `0` a `n` onde `n = m-1` e `m` é quantidade de dígitos que devem ser explorados por foça bruta.

Depois é criada uma função que testa por convolução se os iteradores indexados de `n` a `1` são válidos ou seja se o `iterador[n]` se esgotou o `iterador[n-1]` avança uma posição e o `iterador[n]` é restaurado, se caso o `iterador[n-1]` se esgotou o `iterador[n-2]` avança uma posição e o `iterador[n-1]` é restaurado,.... se caso o `iterador[1]` se esgotou o `iterador[0]` avança uma posição e o `iterador[1]` é restaurado. Finalmente a função termina testando a validade do `iterador[0]` caso o mesmo tenha se esgotado é retornado false indicando que todas as combinação foram obtidas.

O código em si opera num loop onde as strings de combinação são montadas a cada iteração do loop, e a cada iteração do loop gerando uma nova combinação de caracteres.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$letras = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numeros = '0123456789';
//Junta letras e números e os separa num array para então criar instância ArrayObject.
$tudo = new ArrayObject(str_split ($letras.$numeros));

$minimo = 5;            //Define o número de caracteres a serem iterados.
$string = 'XXXXX';      //Define o prefixo do resultado.
$iteradores = [];       //Inicializa o array contendo os iteradores.

//Inicializa e armazena o número especificado de iteradores.
for($i=1; $i<=$minimo; $i++){
   $iteradores[] = $tudo->getIterator();
}

//Função de validação aplicada aos iteradores.
function iterar($iter){
    //Do iterador[n](último) ao iterador[1](segundo iterador)... 
    for($i=count($iter) - 1; $i>0; $i--){
        //...se o iterador se esgotou....
        if (!$iter[$i]->valid()) {                 
            $iter[$i]->seek(0);                   //...o renova.
            $iter[$i-1]->next();                  //...itera o seu antecessor.
        }
    }
    return $iter[0]->valid();                     //Retorna o estado do primeiro iterador, enquanto for válido ainda existem combinações a serem geradas.
};

//Enquanto houver combinações...
while(iterar($iteradores)){
    $str = $iteradores[0]->current();                //...obtém o primeiro caractere após o prefixo.
    //...Obtém os caracteres consecutivos da esquerda para direita...
    for($i=0; $i<count($iteradores); $i++){
        $str .= $iteradores[$i]->current();
    }
    $iteradores[count($iteradores) - 1]->next();     //Prepara a nova combinação.

    $base = $string.$str;                            
    echo $base.PHP_EOL;                              
}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/guX4D4). PS: No modo free são permitidos apenas 5s de execução do código, então ele para abruptamente, copie teste no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.</sup>

Comment: Incrivel, nunca tinha usado nem estudado sobre a classe `ArrayObject`. Com certeza irei me aprofundar mais sobre a mesma! Muito obrigado.